# Cannot push to Hg project on Codeplex

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, codeplex

I am trying to push changes to my codeplex project that is using mercurial.

I receive the following error:

abort: HTTP Error 500: abandoned transaction found - run hg recover

I have tried on my home PC and I get the same error.

I run "hg recover" and it says:

no interrupted transaction available

I know there is another simiar question here on SO.  Some folks on the Net reckon one should run the recovery on the remote repository.  I cannot do that.  I have mailed the codeplex folks but haven't heard back.

Any ideas?

Comment: The message about running `hg recover` is coming from the server side, so you would need to run the command on the remote repository (probably not possible?)

Comment: Nope.  Guess I'm gonna have to wait for the codeplex folks :)

Comment: I've not used codeplex (and I've only just started using bitbucket), so my only suggestion would be to look at the repository page on the codeplex website and see what that says. Not much help, really. One thing to note is that googling around shows that the problem can occur due to pushes with a large number of changesets - I guess the http server times out, causing the push to fail.

Comment: It started when I had only 1 changeset --- up to three now but that seems quite low (and not *many* files at that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue was on the remote repository hosted on codeplex.  The codeplex folks were so kind as to fix the issue :)

Comment: It would be nice to know what solved it.. This is not an answer.

Comment: @Sire: As stated in the answer the codeplex people fixed the issue.  Since SO wants an answer this is it.

Answer (score 25):

For anyone having this problem on their own hg repo you need to run **hg recover *on the remote repo***. It's a very simple fix but the error messages doesn't make this obvious.

(This is mentioned above, I just want to make it very clear).

Comment: I tried everything I could find.  Remember that I cannot run anything on the server side.  It is on codeplex.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the CodePlex [Contact Us](https://www.codeplex.com/site/contact) form and say what error you're getting and we'll run "hg recover" on your project for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that is where the "I have mailed the codeplex folks but haven't heard back." comes in :) --- I actually did use the "Contact Us" form so maybe "mailed" was the wrong word to use.