# Fix Mercurial Codeplex repository - always rollback

Tags: mercurial, codeplex

I try to push my latest changes to a Codeplex repository. However I always do get a rollback (see below). What are my options?

1. I have tried `force` and `debug` options, no further details or acceptance on the changes.
2. Tried to delete the whole repository (deleting the whole Codeplex project is no good option) - but haven't found a way. Wanted to "push completely new".
3. Somebody here has written in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326950/cannot-push-to-hg-project-on-codeplex), I should run recover. I have tried `recover` and `hg recover`, but always the same rollback.

So what can I do?

The little information I get:

```
pushing to https://hg.codeplex.com/myproject
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
[command returned code 1 Sat Oct 27 21:40:53 2012]
```

[image: Mercurial options]
Have tried `recover` and `hg recover`

Edit:

As of comment below, updated to Tortoise / Hg 2.5.1/2.3.2 - just for the sake of trying it. Situation unchanged, will try the other hint.

Comment: You can try 1/ push in console with `-v --debug` 2/ clone Codeplex repo (part) into additional local repo and push into new 3/ `push -r` in order to push only part in one transaction

Comment: BTW, 2.4.3 is *two versions below* of last release

Comment: Have you tried it with the `--debug` flag enabled? If you get *any* output, post it here.

Comment: Yep, no output except what I have posted above. This output is already with --debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment above, here is what I did.

1. Backup of my local directory
2. Cloning old version again from Codeplex
3. Copying local files from backup (not the repository, only the files)
4. Commit and push now OK

Drawback: Looses me so history between Codeplex and local version.
**Any better ideas still appreciated.**

Comment: You could try: a) after 2 push into "new local clone" from "old local clone"/pull in the inverse direction b) save not-pushed changesets as patches and apply to "new local clone" . Both versions store full history